# attempting to restart mysql after a fresh reinstall

Tags: mysql

I'm attempting to restart mysql using:

```
sudo service mysql start
```

I had followed some steps to reset the password and it didn't work neither am I able to start it again.

The error message:

```
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-01-16 01:59:30 UTC; 13s ago
  Process: 9234 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 9212 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 7109 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jan 16 01:59:29 ip-172-26-2-13 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 16 01:59:29 ip-172-26-2-13 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
Jan 16 01:59:30 ip-172-26-2-13 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jan 16 01:59:30 ip-172-26-2-13 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Jan 16 01:59:30 ip-172-26-2-13 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Jan 16 01:59:30 ip-172-26-2-13 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jan 16 01:59:30 ip-172-26-2-13 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 16 01:59:30 ip-172-26-2-13 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

I also tried to remove it and reinstall it using sudo apt-get and I get the same error.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

EDITED ran: `sudo journalctl -b -u mysql`

```
Jan 16 01:33:03 ip-172-26-2-13 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jan 16 01:33:03 ip-172-26-2-13 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
Jan 16 01:33:03 ip-172-26-2-13 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Jan 16 01:33:03 ip-172-26-2-13 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Jan 16 01:33:04 ip-172-26-2-13 mysqld[4170]: Initialization of mysqld failed: 0
Jan 16 01:33:04 ip-172-26-2-13 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 16 01:33:04 ip-172-26-2-13 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 16 01:33:04 ip-172-26-2-13 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

Comment: Could you please attach the output of: `sudo  journalctl -b -u mysql`

Comment: I second to @MirceaVutcovici. Also an error.log of mysql would be helpful as well. Since you removed and reinstalled, it could be also that your diskspace is overloaded.

Comment: Good odds the system logs or journalctl will tell you that it's either a permission issue or apparmor settings. MySQL acts up with apparmor quite often in my experience. Could you provide the requested logs?

Comment: I updated the journalctl run.  How would I get the requested logs?

Comment: dba.stackexchange.com might be a more focused place to ask this sort of question.

Comment: Ok any way to move it over?  Or I just have to re ask it?  @RickJames